# Delphi: Generate dependency graph by class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In Visual Studio I can “Generate dependency graph by class” how do I do this in Delphi-XE2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Delphi Class Explorer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Viewing_Hierarchy_of_Classes,_Interfaces,_and_Types_in_the_Class_Explorer)

Also, you have a similar option by using [GExperts's](http://www.gexperts.org/) class browser feature

Classes can be viewed as a flat list or tree-structured hierarchy.

[image]